# Difference of prime products

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Using the first seven primes $(2,3,5,7,11,13,17)$, the largest difference that can be created from products of these primes is $5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17-2\cdot 3=85079$. What is the 2nd smallest ($1$ is possible...maybe finding that first would help...I'll let you find it and decide)? Can you prove that it is the 2nd smallest? The best I've found is $107$.

Comment: Is there any principled reason to omit $3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17 - 2 = 255253$ as a larger difference of products?

Comment: Do you have to use all primes? Because $3\cdot 5-7\cdot 2=1$.

Comment: By @ThomasAndrews question, if not, you can get $2$ as a $13 - 11$.

Comment: Also, is difference used as absolute difference? This becomes a very different problem if you're allowed to take negative results, such as $2 - 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17$.

Comment: Brute force shows that 107 is the second best you can do. It's not surprising the value will be large - it has to be not divisible by any of these primes, at least...

Comment: We could do better if prime powers were allowed.

Comment: Hardmath, no, just that 2 isn't a product. Thomas Andrews, yes, I probably could have made that clearer...sorry. Axoren, yes, absolute difference. Thomas, how did you brute force it? Just list each possibility? Curious if there's a way to KNOW that 107 is best once you've found it.

Comment: Hardmath, interesting thought. I suppose that you mean $2^x$, $3^y$ etc. As we can guarantee that 2 though 18 are impossible, would 19 be possible? Is there proof based on some numeric principle that 19 would be possible before starting?

Comment: Ok, so I got 19 using Hardmath's revised problem. 2 questions remain: 1. Was I guaranteed to be able to do so by some principle? 2. Can we guarantee by some principle that 107 is the lowest possible without changing the rules? Looking for predictive value.